# «Гугл класс». Как правильно писать?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно по-орфографически?

1. Я люблю приложение гугл класс.
2. Я люблю приложение гугл-класс.
3. Я люблю приложение Гугл-Класс
4. Я люблю приложение Гугл-класс.
5. Я люблю приложение Google класс.
6. Я люблю приложение Google Класс.

Comment: А где кавычки??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взять **два варианта.**

Я люблю приложение **Google Класс**. Это имя собственное (вариант записи из Википедии). С прописной буквы пишутся оба слова: **Google** — первое слово названия, **Класс** — условное название.

Я люблю приложение ***Гугл-класс***. В русском варианте лучше использовать дефисное написание одного слова.

**Примеры** (прописная и строчная буква):  Я полез смотреть в *Гугл*, где там эта Рига. Звонок в техподдержку: — У меня *гугл* не открывается...

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148839/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.